# Pass data to partial class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderpartial

I am trying to pass a model to my partial class in asp.net however it keeps giving me the following error:
[image: stack trace]

I tried calling the partial class the following ways:

```
 <section id="categoryPartial">
    @*1*@   @Html.Partial("_CategoryPartial", new EindopdrServer.Models.Category())
    @*2*@   @Html.Partial("_CategoryPartial", new EindopdrServer.Models.Category{ Name => Model.Name })
    @*3*@   @Html.RenderPartial("_CategoryPartial", new EindopdrServer.Models.Category { Name => Model.Name })
 </section>
```

My partial class:

```
@model IEnumerable<EindopdrServer.Models.Category>

<table>
    <tr>
       @if(Model != null){
            @foreach (var item in Model) {    
                <td class="categoryPartial">
                    <a href="Products/SearchIndex?productGenre=@item.Name"><b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</b></a>
                </td>    
            }
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

Any solutions?

After removing the @ and if statement:
[image]

Comment: Could you post a full stack trace?

Comment: I hope it is readable.

Answer (score 3):

Because the `if`-statement is code, and not markup, the `foreach` is already considered code. You don't need to have `@` before it.

So, simply remove the `@` character before the `foreach`

Comment: For another error: Firstly, check display name: item=>item.Name, Second, may be item is null etc.